# Build a project wheel with rpy2 dependencies

Tags: rpy2, python-wheel

Does anyone know how to specify the dependencies correctly to package a python project that uses rpy2 and R packages like data.table for example?

The aim is to then deploy it onto databricks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Python build tools allow to specify Python dependencies but don't have any provisions to specify non-Python dependencies. `rpy2` is a Python dependency and can be specified but R packages? No way.

Comment: `conda` allows to specify non-Python dependencies that can be installed from conda repositories. System package managers like DEB or RPM allow to specify non-Python dependencies that can be installed from distribution mirrors but that's very much non-portable.